# How to get kind of group by result set like this.

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this result set into a #temptable like this which i got from joining 2 tables parent and child. Here is JOIN SQL QUERY I have

```
    SELECT P.Parent_Id, C.Child_ID,   C.C1_PID   , C.C2_PID
FROM PARENT P INNER JOIN CHILD C ON P.Parent_Id
CASE 
WHEN C.C1_PID = '' OR C.C1_PID IS NULL 
THEN C.C2_PID
WHEN C.C1_PID <>'' THEN C.C1_PID
END
```

current #temptable result set I am getting

```
Parent_Id  Child_ID   C1_PID    C2_PID
========  =========  ======== =========
 1          X1          1       1
 1          X2                  1
 1          X3          1       
 2          Y1                  2
 2          Y2                  2
 2          Y3                  2
 3          Z1          3       3
 3          Z2          3       3
 3          Z3          3       3

 Now I would like to convert result set of this #temptable to like this below
What I want to show IS DISPLAY EMPTY LIKE A SPACE OR BLANK OR NULL IN PLACE OF CHILD COLUMNS DATA AND SHOW THE CHILD DATA IN NEXT ROW WITH BLANK OR NULL OR EMPTY SPACE IN PLACE OF PARENT ID 


Parent_Id  Child_ID   C1_PID    C2_PID
========  =========  ======== =========
 1          
            X1          1       1       
            X2                  1
            X3          1       
 2          
            Y1                  2
            Y2                  2
            Y3                  2
 3                      
            Z1          3       3
            Z2          3       3
            Z3          3       3
```

Comment: And, er... What is the logic behind the second result set? Because the only difference I see is one row for parent_id 1 has been made blank but there's no logic I can see as to why that would the only blank row...

Comment: And, er... every child has 3 parents? (Therefore this is not a mammalian example.)

Comment: What logic are you applying to your temp table to get your result set?

Comment: have you found any answer useful? can you please accept one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have `Dataset` as below :

```
Parent_Id  Child_ID   C1_PID    C2_PID
========  =========  ======== =========
 1          X1          1       1
 1          X2                  1
 1          X3          1       
 2          Y1                  2
 2          Y2                  2
 2          Y3                  2
 3          Z1          3       3
 3          Z2          3       3
 3          Z3          3       3
```

And you want to display above `Dataset` as in below format :

```
Parent_Id  Child_ID   C1_PID    C2_PID
========  =========  ======== =========
 1          
            X1          1       1       
            X2                  1
            X3          1       
 2          
            Y1                  2
            Y2                  2
            Y3                  2
 3                      
            Z1          3       3
            Z2          3       3
            Z3          3       3
```

If, all above are correct, then Just Try below `SQL Query` which could help you to achieve the above result :

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (
     SELECT Parent_Id,
            Child_ID,
            C1_PID,
            C2_PID
     FROM #TM
     UNION
     SELECT Parent_Id,
            NULL Child_ID,
            NULL C1_PID,
            NULL C2_PID
     FROM #TM),
     CTE1
     AS (
     SELECT Parent_Id,
            Child_ID,
            C1_PID,
            C2_PID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Parent_Id ORDER BY Parent_Id) RN
     FROM CTE)
     SELECT CASE
                WHEN RN > 1
                THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), '')
                ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), Parent_Id)
            END AS Parent_Id,
            ISNULL(Child_ID, '') Child_ID,
            ISNULL(C1_PID, '') C1_PID,
            ISNULL(C2_PID, '') C2_PID
     FROM CTE1;
```

**Desired Output :**

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much..this is perfect and solved my issue! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now, after your edit, I have understood, my solution is very simple, take a look:

```
;with
f as (
    select Parent_Id, null Child_ID, null C1_PID, null C2_PID from #temptable
    union
    select * from #temptable
)
select 
    CASE WHEN Child_ID IS NULL THEN Parent_Id ELSE NULL END Parent_Id,
    Child_ID, C1_PID, C2_PID
from f
order by f.Parent_Id, child_id
```

**BE CAREFUL**
It is mandatory to specify the `ORDER BY` clause because SQL does NOT have "insert order" you need to specify a condition or result may be unexpected.

Comment: Thank you for responding..and apologize as my requested logic was not clear..I have improved my question now. Could you please check now if you any thoughts on this. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Stark. This almost solved my problem but the below Answer solved my scenario better. But this was perfect too. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest for use this query for with better performance

```
                /*NULL Columns Which you don't want data*/
SELECT  CASE  WHEN ID = 1 THEN Parent_Id END AS Parent_Id,
        CASE  WHEN ID != 1 THEN Child_ID END AS Child_ID,
        CASE  WHEN ID != 1 THEN C1_PID END AS C1_PID,
        CASE  WHEN ID != 1 THEN C2_PID END AS C2_PID
FROM 
(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Parent_Id ORDER BY Parent_Id)ID,Parent_ID,Child_ID,C1_PID,C2_PID
        FROM 
        (
            /*This is your Query*/
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY P.Parent_Id ORDER BY P.Parent_Id)ID, P.Parent_Id, C.Child_ID, C.C1_PID, C.C2_PID
            FROM    @PARENT P
            INNER JOIN @CHILD C ON P.Parent_Id=( CASE WHEN C.C1_PID='' OR C.C1_PID IS NULL THEN C.C2_PID
                                                                WHEN C.C1_PID<>'' THEN C.C1_PID END )
        )Y
        /*Logic Query*/
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (  SELECT 1 PId
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT 1 PId

                            ) X ON X.PId = Y.ID
)FinalData
```